# Gyroscope: how to transform the data to world coordination system on smartphone?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, coordinate-transformation

The questions that relevant are about the accelerometer data, not gyroscope. I want to know whether I can transform the gyroscope data from device coordination system to world coordination system?

Someone suppose that we can use Euler Angle or quaternion, but they didn't give a good example about gyroscope. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a device/world coordination system? A gyroscope measures orientation and momentum in formats like radians per second or orientation in degrees. If you want to calculate position based on things like gyroscope data, a keyword is "inertial measurement unit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gyroscope along with accelerometer and magnetometer can give the world co-ordinate system correctly.

Gyroscope is generally used to calculate the relative angular changes rather than the absolute world direction.

I have worked on Indoor Positioning system using these. 
Please find the Indoor tracking application here : 
https://github.com/ramakanthd92/IndoorMagMap

A publication for the same can be found here http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7106948/

Hope this helps

Comment: Does the gyroscope data represent the real angular changes of the device or smaller because of the device coordinate system?

Comment: Gyroscope gives the angular changes of the device. This can be added to the direction of the device calculated using magnetometer & accelerometer to find the new world co-ordinate system direction